# Error when using Toast

Tags: android

I use Toast to display some message but have some trouble. There is my code:

```
  private Button btPush;
    private EditText etxMessage;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btPush = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btPushMe);
        btPush.setOnClickListener(sayHello);

        etxMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    }

    View.OnClickListener sayHello = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            LayoutInflater inflated = getLayoutInflater();
            View layout = inflated.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout));
            String string = etxMessage.getText().toString();
            Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
            toast.setText(string);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, 0, 0);
            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setView(layout);
            toast.show();
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),string,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
```

If I use:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),string,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

It works!

Comment: what is the error you are getting???

Comment: Can you post your logcat?

Answer (score 1):

Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this,"YOUR TEXT HERE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Answer (score 0):

You can try this ..if the error still remain then paste your log-cat output it will be easy for us to give you answer

```
      Toast msg = Toast.makeText(ToastExample.this,"YOUR TEXT HERE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);     
   msg.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
LayoutInflater inflated = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflated.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out the layout inflating like this :

```
LayoutInflater inflated = LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);     
View layout = inflated.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to use Toast to display a message...

using Toast object ...
**Toast toast = new Toast(YourClassName.this);**

or 
Trying to display from click event then use this code...
but this 'v' is a object of View .

**Toast toast = new Toast(v.getContext());**

or

and below code you can use anywhere inside YourActivityClass... 
**Toast.makeText(YourClassName.this,"Your Message",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();**